# Eclipse reopen file at last viewed position

Tags: eclipse, file, editing

Eclipse always opens a file from the top. However, I want to open it at the last viewed position because it is likely that I have to continue editing near this position (see also [Locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference)). Furthermore, it makes sense to continue navigation at this place because it is where I left and so I have this relatively fresh in my mind. Thus, it gives me orientation. Finding the last viewed position can be time consuming.

Some other editors, e.g., Visual Studio Code show the last viewed position when opening a file. This little change helps me a lot to navigate and edit code in re-opened files.

Is it possible to get the same behavior in Eclipse, i.e., re-open files at the last viewed position?

Comment: Is there a feature request for this in Bugzilla?

Comment: The [_Eclipse Folding Plugin_](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-folding-plugin) claims to have this feature.

Comment: Indeed the "Eclipse Folding Plugin" says that restoring the cursor position is a feature. However, there is no update site anymore for this plugin. The links to external sites do not work. Last update was 2014. I am pretty confident that this plugin is dead now (and probably for good).

Comment: I found some feature requests on bugzilla. They range from 2004 to 2008 with some comments 2015. Some are marked as WONTFIX. In one bug there is a mention of a plugin "EditorPosition" which provided this feature but is also dead (already in 2008). So I guess there is no such feature per default in Eclipse and I would have to come up with my own solution. (related bugzilla tickets: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=56613 | https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=127145 | https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=216163 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this feature to my plugin [RecentEditors](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/recent-editors).

The current scroll position and caret position of editors is persisted and can be restored when an editor is re-opened. This enables to continue editing at the last viewed position.

Furthermore, the plugin adds a new dialog to see and re-open recently closed files.

You find the plugin on the [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/recent-editors), and [GitHub](https://github.com/achimmihca/RecentEditors).

Comment: Fun fact: I created this plugin to re-open recently closed files. Adding the feature to persist and restore the last viewed position (and selection) took only a few hours. I am sure Eclipse devs could have added this even faster to their platform. Astonishing that none of them felt the need to do so in the last 15 years...

Comment: The Eclipse IDE packages are shipped with Mylyn with a similar solution that in addition supports task switching (but which requires creating tasks). Therefore, your addition might be a nice enhancement. Please [contribute it](https://www.eclipse.org/contribute/). The Eclipse IDE is community driven. Become a part of it.