# Netbeans re-open (Java) file at last viewed position

Tags: java, file, netbeans

Netbeans always opens (Java) files from the top. However, I want to open them at the last viewed position because it is likely that I have to continue editing near this position (see also [Locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference)). Furthermore, it makes sense to continue navigation at this place because it is where I left and so I have this relatively fresh in my mind. Thus, it gives me orientation. Finding the last viewed position can be time consuming.

Some other editors, e.g., Visual Studio Code show the last viewed position when opening a file. This little change helps me a lot to navigate and edit code in re-opened files. [I once asked the same for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57017899/eclipse-reopen-file-at-last-viewed-position) but now I have to use Netbeans.

Similar behaviour can be observed in modern browsers. Scroll down a page, close the tab, reopen the tab from the history. The page will be opened on the same scroll position where you have left.

Is it possible to get the same behavior in Netbeans, i.e., re-open files at the last viewed position? I am using Netbeans 11.2.

---

Steps to reproduce in Netbeans:

Open a file, scroll down in that file and select some text, close the file, click on "file > open recent file > [THE FILE]" in the menu bar.

Now, the selection and scroll pos is gone but I want to continue where I have left the file.

Comment: It works for me.  Try to reset your NetBeans config files.

Comment: I cannot revert all config to defaults, because there are also company code styles configured for example. Can somebody point me to the specific field that I need to change?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem on 11.2. Can you update your question to describe the exact steps needed to provoke this issue with enough detail that others can attempt to reproduce it? I suspect that there are certain conditions that need to be met for you to encounter this issue, or am I not properly understanding your concern. To be clear, if the cursor is at some arbitrary position within the file and I restart NetBeans that position is preserved. But if I close and reopen the file within a NetBeans session, the cursor is at the start of the file, though that seems appropriate to me.

Comment: I added steps to reproduce. "If I close and reopen the file within a NetBeans session, the cursor is at the start of the file". Indeed, this behaviour is not wrong, but I would find it more productive when it opens the file where I left it. Is there maybe a plugin to achieve that?